# Handling event handlers in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, angularjs, event-handling

I am using a jquery plugin using angular directive.  I am having a problem handling the angular event handlers.  I have a keydown event handler in angular and the jquery plugin have the same event handler too.  When i do any key down event, angular detects the event returns false / event.preventDefault().  But it still calls the  event handler in jquery plugin.  Any idea how can i stop the event handlers from going to jquery event handler from angular ?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not be handling Angular events along with jQuery event in the first place.
But if you must, try using `event.stopPropagation()`

If that doesn't cut it, you can check whether the event was stopped in your jQuery:

```
event.isPropagationStopped()
```

which returns a boolean. http://api.jquery.com/event.isPropagationStopped/

Worst case scenario, you hold a shared flag (variable visible in scope to both the angular event handler and the jQuery event handler), always be sure to delay the jQuery handler for a couple of ms, and then in your angular handler raise the `isHandled` flag. When it comes to your jQuery event handler: if flag is `false` handle event. if flag is `true` lower flag and return without handling.

But your best bet is to handle events only in Angular and lose the jQuery.

Comment: i tried the event.stopPropagation, it gives me true but still the jquery handler is instantiated ?  How can i fix this with timeout ?

Comment: So if in your jQuery event handler you see that event.isPropagationStopped() then exit and don't handle the event.

Comment: i am doing this in angualar, using jquery

Comment: can you write up a quick plunker/jsfiddle?

Comment: can you guide me how can i stop the other event handler with delay ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. As far as I could tell - you have 2 event handlers firing for the same event. Your only real problem is if they fire simultaneously which I don't think is the situation here. You could use $timeout (or setTimeout) on the event handler that wish to delay in order to check if it should handle the event.